# Linq GROUP & SUM the same columns from different tables

Tags: linq, group-by, ef-code-first, sum

I'm trying to combine these 2 Linq queries into 1:

```
var query = from s in _context.Set<StockInventoryItem>()
                        where s.StockCatalogueItemId == id
                        group s by s.StockType  into g
                        select new
                        {
                            inStock = g.Sum(x => x.QtyInStock),
                        };

        var query2 = from p in _context.Set<PurchaseOrderItem>()
                     where p.StockCatalogueItemId == id
                     group p by p.StockType into g2
                     select new
                     {
                         onOrder = g2.Sum(x => x.QtyStillDue)
                     };
```

Note that the filtering, grouping and output is the same from both tables, and I want the results to look like this:

```
 StockType  inStock  onOrder
+----------+--------+--------+
  Type 1      4        3
+----------+--------+--------+
  Type 2      0        1
```

i.e. Quantities grouped by `StockType`

This is EF code first and there is no direct relationship between these tables, which is why I'm trying this query in the service layer so I can access both entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to "shoehorn" both groups into the same sequence with anonymous types and `Concat`, and then count the results separately, like this:

```
var query = _context.Set<StockInventoryItem>()
    .Where(ii => ii.StockCatalogueItemId == id)
    .Select(ii => new {
        II = ii, PO = (PurchaseOrderItem)null
    }).Concat(_context.Set<PurchaseOrderItem>()
    .Where(po => po.StockCatalogueItemId == id)
    .Select(po => new {
        II = (StockInventoryItem)null, PO = po
    })).GroupBy(p => II != null ? ii.StockType : PO.StockType)
    .Select(g => new {
        InStock = g.Sum(p => p.II != null ? p.II.QtyInStock : 0)
    ,   OnOrder = g.Sum(p => p.PO != null ? p.PO.QtyStillDue: 0)
    });
```